# Is there an elegant way (short and efficient) to compare if all the values in 1 int[] array are lesser than or equals to another int[] array?

Tags: java

As of now I know the same old way of just doing a for loop to compare, but is there an even more efficient (both shorter to write and faster) way of doing it? Both arrays are of length n, so it's running in O(n) time now.

Comment: By the "same old way," I assume you mean finding the max of one (O(n)) and the min of the other (O(n)) and comparing those two values? If you don't know anything about the two arrays (ie if they're not sorted), then no, you're not going to get any faster than that. If you mean two nested loops, then it's not running in O(n) time right now.

Comment: Short and efficient are not the same thing. Using  `Arrays.stream(arrayA).max().getAsInt();` is short on your part,  but that still  internally uses a loop to examine every member on turn and is probably no more efficient timewise that writing the loop yourself. Still, I would use the streaming. But if you also wanted to know whether the one array is greater than all of the other, I would write my own loop instead of streaming  twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the biggest integer in array **A** is lower than the lowest integer in array **B**.

you can get those values by if java 8

```
int[] arrayA = ...;
int max = Arrays.stream(arrayA).max().getAsInt();
int[] arrayB = ...;
int min = Arrays.stream(arrayB).min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: You can get the highest and lowest values without sorting.

Comment: Yes, if I'm not wrong, Java's sort method makes it O (n log (n)).

Comment: @shmosel ah yes, Math.min and Math.max yes?

Comment: Sorting can't get faster than n log(n), Java or otherwise.

Comment: @bryancresswell No, you would have to iterate through the arrays (as in the updated solution), but it's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing every value of the first array to every value of the second then yes. Write two short loops, one getting the max of one array and one getting the min of the other and then compare these values. You could even get both the max of one and the min of the other on the same loop if they always have the same number of values.

Comment: Ah great! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to compare arrays for each elements, than you need to loop them and it'll take O(n) only if both arrays are sorted, except it'll take O(n^2).